# How to fill dynamic table using java graph data structure

Tags: java, jsf-2

Can anyone advise how to fill below table? The header and first column is dynamic. If I can populate the table data then I can print it in the `UI`

[image]

Data is retrieved from the `DB` and set to the `Product` object. The `Product` object contains the matching `plans`. Some products doesn't have all the `plans`. So there should be an empty `plan` object in that particular index of the `pricePlanList`.

```
Public class Product{

    // price plans this object can have.
  private ArrayList pricePlanList = new ArrayList();


  public void setPricePlanList(ArrayList list){
     this.pricePlanList = list;
  }

  public ArrayList getPricePlanList(){
     returnn pricePlanList;
  }
}
```

I can populate this in the jsf view but need to fill the data structure properly. Some `product` have few plans, some `product` has all the plans. so when populate the columns in the view table, it's not working properly. Because some product has less `plans` objects in the list, meaning less columns. also not matching to relevant column.

See `Product 2` doesn't have `Plan 1` in the `DB`. so `Product2` object should have a second `plan` object but without value.

Is there any direct `java` `data structure` I can use? else I have to loop it and fill the missing object to build this table?